# Why are my Vim keyboard shortcuts so slow?

Tags: vim

I've created myself the following vim shortcut: `map <Leader>c magg=G'a<CR>`

When I use it, there's a pretty noticeable 2-second lag happening before my file is actually indented. If I manually type `magg=G'a`, the problem doesn't happen. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have other mappings that start with `<Leader>c`, so Vim has to wait to resolve the ambiguity; `:verbose map <Leader>c` will tell you. Then, just choose different keys for one to get immediate response.

Also, [you should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.